# Alternative of Requests in django

Tags: django, django-views, python-requests, django-authentication, django-sessions

In my project I'm trying to hit a url(which is running in same project) in my view.

so in simplest way I can explain here.

```
@login_required
def my_api_view(request):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        # do stuff
        return JsonResponse()

# and its url is `/api/get-info/`
```

another view  which is consuming above api

```
@login_required
def show_info(request):
    url = get_base_url  + /api/get-info/  # http://localhost:8000/api/get-info/
    r = requests.get(url)

    return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

Now I have to use same session (login required) so when I hit the url using `requests` it complains that user is not loggedin which is obviously correct.

How can I do this elegantly and efficienty. session use of logged in user. (I dont want to call the view as a function, I want to hit the api-url end point and consume.

PS: we have something similar in django Test `self.client.get(...)`

Comment: Why are you trying to use HTTP instead of just calling the other view function directly? Or even better, why not factor the logic out into a separate function / method / whatever that will be called by both views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call that view function and pass the `request` object as parameter to it.

```
@login_required
def show_info(request):
    r = my_api_view(request)
    return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

Or a better option would be to simply separate the logic into a separate function, as mentioned by @koniiiik in the comments.

**EDIT:** Or if you really want to hit the URL endpoint, you can simply pass on the cookie values to the request you make.

```
@login_required
def show_info(request):
    url = get_base_url  + "/api/get-info/"  # http://localhost:8000/api/get-info/
    r = requests.get(url, cookies=request.COOKIES)
    return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

Comment: @Wendy - Have a look at the edit. Maybe that will help you.